# How to get date as string from datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the following datepicker:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="register_birth_date" class="input-group date">
        <input id="register_birth_input" class="input_edit text-center" type="text" th:placeholder="#{label.birthday}"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#register_birth_date").datetimepicker({
                locale : "de",
                format : "DD.MM.YYYY",
                maxDate: "0"
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

And to get the value from that input i do the following with jQuery:

```
var inputDateOfBirth = $("#register_birth_input").val();

console.log("date: " + inputDateOfBirth);
```

And the result is:

```
date: 625964400000
```

I dont want to get the date as long. I want to get it as string like i defined the format as `DD.MM.YYYY` because the date of birth needs to be the same in every time zone.

How can i get it as string?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the date is being returned in milliseconds.

```js
var inputDateOfBirth = 625964400000; // $("#register_birth_input").val();
var date = new Date(inputDateOfBirth);
console.log("date: " + inputDateOfBirth);

var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
var year = date.getYear();
    
console.log("date: " + day + "." + month + "." + year);
```

This should return the date in an acceptable format.

Comment: No. I cant use that. If i work with milliseconds you get wrong date of birth for several locals. i need to get the input directly. The input format is a string "DD.MM.YYYY" and this input i need to get.

Comment: @Mulgard I updated my answer - is this more what you need?

Comment: No. I cant use the milliseconds. Ok: The user can choose the date of birth and the result ist for example "11.02.1986". What no happens is that this date is getting converted into milliseconds and is returned. And exactly this is bad because "11.02.1986" in germany in milliseconds is the "10.02.1986" in america for example. so what i need is to directly get the string from the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. For your code to work change `var date = new Date(625964400000);` to `var date = new Date(inputDateOfBirth);`

```js
function GetDateTime(dt) {
  var date = dt.getDate();
  var month = parseInt(dt.getMonth()) + 1;
  var year = dt.getUTCFullYear();
  if (date < 10) {
    date = "0" + date;
  }
  if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }
  if (year < 10) {
    year = "0" + year;
  }
  return date + "." + month + "." + year;
}

var date = new Date(625964400000);
console.log(GetDateTime(date));
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi. When i copy your code and log the result it prings "11.02.1989" instead of "02.11.1989"

Comment: it's working fine for me. can you post your complete code in a fiddle!

Comment: @Mulgard : What is the value printed when trying `console.log(date);` ??

Comment: Please post the output of `console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());`